# The mappings //Entity and //Entity are inconsistent with each other - Symfony2/Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Have spent literally the last 2 hours trying to fix this issue. I'm sure it's something stupid I am overlooking but It's properly got me stuck.

I am getting this error when I try and validate my database :

```
 [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipe' mapping is     invalid:
 * The mappings BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipe#products and BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\Products#recipes are incosistent with each other.
 * The mappings BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipe#recipes and BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\Recipes#products are incosistent with each other.

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\Products' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\Products#recipes and BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipe#recipes are incosistent with each other.

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\Recipes' mapping is invalid:
* The mappings BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\Recipes#products and BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipe#products are incosistent with each other.
```

I thought I had got my Inverse and Mapped by's wrong. So (I think) I have tried every possible combination but to no avail.

Here's my mapping files.

```
//Recipe.orm.yml
   oneToMany:
    products:
      mappedBy: productsProductRecipe
      cascade: ["all"]

//Products.orm.yml
   oneToMany:
    recipes:
      targetEntity: ProductRecipe
      mappedBy: recipes
      cascade: ["all"]

//ProductRecipe.orm.yml
BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipe:
type: entity
table: ProductRecipe
repositoryClass: BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipeRepository

id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    ammount:
        type: decimal
        presision: 10
        scale: 2

   manyToOne:
    products:
      targetEntity: Products
      inversedBy: recipes
      joinColumn:
        name: product_id
        referencedColumnName: id
    recipes:
      targetEntity: Recipes
      inversedBy: products
      joinColumn:
        name: recipe_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

I have been using Doctrine:Generate:Entities for my entities so I won't paste them here unless asked for them. All the setters and getters are there.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `ProductRecipe` entity? It seems like you are trying to manually define a `ManyToMany` relationship.

Comment: I have an extra field in ProductRecipe so can't use Many2Many (I think?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recipe.orm.yml

```
   oneToMany:
        products:
            targetEntity: ProductRecipe // Not present before
            mappedBy: recipes // Previously "productsProductRecipe"
            cascade: ["all"]
```

Products.orm.yml `\\ Should rename for singular, also your relation is for Product`

```
    oneToMany:
        recipes:
            targetEntity: ProductRecipe
            mappedBy: products // Previously "recipes"
            cascade: ["all"]
```

ProductRecipe.orm.yml

```
BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipe:
    type: entity
    table: ProductRecipe
    repositoryClass: BC\InventoryBundle\Entity\ProductRecipeRepository

    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        amount: // Previously "ammount"
            type: decimal
            presision: 10
            scale: 2

    manyToOne:
        products:
            targetEntity: Product
                // "Products" is named correctly but recipe is singular
                // so for the sake of uniformity 
            inversedBy: recipes
            joinColumn:
                name: product_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        recipes:
            targetEntity: Recipe 
                // Previously "Recipes", incorrect entity name
            inversedBy: products
            joinColumn:
                name: recipe_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Just at a cursory glance... It could be wrong though.

Comment: Your change to the inverses fixed it for me thank-you. The other changes you made were mistakes I made when copying but thank-you all the same.

Comment: I assumed as much but would have felt dirty having to edit. Glad it's sorted.